# What will be the recommended approach to initialize view (UI) elements in android, OnCreate() or OnStart() method?

Tags: android

I have seen one of the tutorial on Firebase android in which they have initialized the `view` (UI) elements in `OnStart()` method of activity instead of `OnCreate()` method.

I know that the 'OnCreate()' method gets called once and 'OnStart()' methods gets called multiple times when we switch between the activities. I did some study but still wanted to know the exact reason why Firebase tutorial did that way.

I want to know what will be the recommended approach to do so and why?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**onCreate** is Called when the activity is first created. This is where you should do all of your normal static set up: create views, bind data to lists, etc. This method also provides you with a Bundle containing the activity's previously frozen state, if there was one. Always followed by onStart().

**onStart** is Called when the activity is becoming visible to the user. Followed by onResume() if the activity comes to the foreground, or onStop() if it becomes hidden.

For Example Let us assume A and B activity, A activity has been created and currently in onStart() method is being called. When one switches to B activity then A's OnStop() method will be called and B activity will be created. Thus OnStart() OnStop() methods are called when you switches onto activities.

So according to your question initialization is done once so it should be done in OnCreate() method if it is done in OnStart() then initialization will takes place every time when you switch between activities.